# Improving prime number generation probability?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, computational-number-theory, probabilistic-number-theory

Deterministic generation of primes in polynomial time is unknown.

1. Is there a way to probablistically in $O(n^c)$ time bound for some $c>0$ generate polynomially $\Omega(n^c)$ many integers in $[0,2^n]$ such that a constant fraction of them are distinct prime numbers?
2. Is there a way to probablistically in $O(n^c)$ polynomial time bound for some $c>0$ generate $\Omega(n^c)$ many integers in $[2^{n-1}+1,2^n]$ such that a constant faction of them are distinct prime numbers?

The standard approach can only choose $O(\frac{n^c}{\log n})$ primes in best case. In all likelihood it performs significantly worse as there is no guarantee same prime will not be reselected.

Comment: Are you familiar with the polymath on generating primes? http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Finding_primes

Comment: @usul it doesn't help since they try deterministic which is a harder problem.

Comment: How will you get the primes? you have only $O(n^c)$ time.